# C# How to escape form's Accept Button from getting triggered

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, acceptbutton

I have a Windows Form, with a `ListView` and a `TextBox` placed right on top of it. Also there is a button named 'Submit' on the Form with `AcceptButton` set to true.

Now, my requirement is that, whenever I load the form and hit Enter, Submit button gets triggered, which is fine. But, when I select the `TextBox` and type something in it and then hit Enter, the focus **should** come to the `ListView` , but not the `AcceptButton`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can change the Accept button based on the focused control or handle `ProcessDialogKey` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `AcceptButton` based on the active control, or as a better option, handle [`ProcessDialogKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processdialogkey(v=vs.110).aspx) yourself. This is the method which contains [the logic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,05717cf915c738b5) for `AcceptButton`.

So you can override it, for example:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (this.ActiveControl == this.textBox1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter on TextBox1 handled.");
            return true; //Prevent further processing
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```